# cPanel Could not determine the nameserver IP addresses for

Tags: cpanel

I'm using cPanel and when I add this IP, the system report with the following message:

> Could not determine the nameserver IP addresses for
>   “filesharingz.org”. Please make sure that the domain is registered
>   with a valid domain registrar.

The domain name is valid registered.
Not sure what is this error, pls help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I have found solution here:
1) From WHM:

Go to WHM >> Server Configuration >> Tweak Settings >> All

Check for the following option “Allow unregistered domains” it might be “Off” on your settings. Change it to “On” if you want to add unregistered domains as Addons.

2) From command line:

Edit the cpanel config file.

vi /var/cpanel/cpanel.config

allowunregistereddomains=0

## Change the above to allowunregistereddomains=1

That’s it, you are now able  to add new unregistered domains.

http://www.ayyolinux.com/could-not-determine-the-nameserver-ip-addresses-for-domain-com-please-make-sure-that-the-domain-is-registered-with-a-valid-domain-registrar-error-adding-addon-domain-cpanel/

Comment: It's probably easiest these days to change this setting in WHM's "Tweak Settings" menu, under the Domains tab.  It's called something like "Allow unregistered domains".